# Configuring Kafka in .NET using jaas

Tags: apache-kafka, jaas

I'm trying to connect to Kafka using the Confluent.Kafka package. However, I need to use jaas as authentication method. I couldn't find a way to do it using the Confluent.Kafka for .NET.

Edit:

I received the following data to connect:

```
bootstrap.servers=pkc.....cloud:9092
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=https
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="********" password="*******";
```

And I'm trying to create the connection like this:

```
var config = new ProducerConfig
{
    BootstrapServers = "pkc.....cloud:9092",
    SslEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm = SslEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm.Https,
    SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslSsl,
    SaslMechanism = SaslMechanism.Plain,
    //Jaas?***
};
```

Do you guys know how can I set the Jaas I received?

Comment: JAAS is Java specific. Are you asking how to add SASL properties?

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, I included more details in the question. I received a jaas and I need to configure somehow in .net

Comment: `sasl.jaas.config` is only for Java clients and can be ignored for librdkafka-based clients

Comment: You might be interested in this example program for Confluent Cloud - https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/ConfluentCloud/Program.cs

Comment: Thank you @OneCricketeer, I was trying to add the jaas instead of just setting the username and password

Answer (score 4):

As @OneCricketeer said, the Jaas is Java specific. What I need is just to set the UserName and Password.

The final code is this:

```
var config = new ProducerConfig
{
    BootstrapServers = "pkc.....cloud:9092",
    SslEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm = SslEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm.Https,
    SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslSsl,
    SaslMechanism = SaslMechanism.Plain,
    SaslUsername = "******",
    SaslPassword = "*****"
};
```